# Spring AOP PointCut only working when Bean defined in ApplicationContext

Tags: spring-aop, pointcut

I am wondering, why my point cuts ins Spring AOP do only work, if I specify my beans containing the join points explicitly in the application context XML.

Normally in my project, all Spring beans are defined over annotations:

```
@Service
@Component
```

configured with

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.base" scoped-proxy="interfaces" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

The beans get created and are usable throughout my application but the point cut is not triggered.

When I specify the bean manually in my application context with

```
<bean class="..." />
```

The point cut is matched and the according advice is executed.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* my.package.base..*.update*(..))")
public void updateDataPointcut() {}
```

AOP is configured in the application context with

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

I have also created a pointcut for Spring Data JPA CrudRepository which works fine.

What is the difference?
Is there a pitfall in the "component-scan" configuration?

Comment: Is your aspect also a `@Component`?

Comment: @kriegaex yes - my pointcut class is annotated with "@Component"  and "@Aspect"

Comment: Did you also activate Spring AOP via either `@Configuration @EnableAspectJAutoProxy public class AppConfig {}` or `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>`?

Comment: I use the config in the application context. I updated my question above

Comment: Two things (1) Do you need `scoped-proxy="interfaces"` in `component-scan` or can it be done away (2) Does the advised class implement any interface ?

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond ad1 -> I am not quite sure. This is legacy-configuration in my project. I can give it a try and remove it. ad2 -> Yes. There is `SpecialImpl implements SpecialInterface` and `SpecialInterface extends BaseInterface`. The Pointcut is set onto the methods of the `BaseInterface`

Comment: `scoped-proxy` is used when a shorter scope bean (*e.g. request  or session*) is injected to wider scope bean(s) viz singleton. Check if there are such beans

Comment: Since the advised bean is implementing interface then JDK proxy is being created as `aop:aspectj-autoproxy` is configured default to use JDK proxy. Thus my suspicion of problem due to mixing of CGLIB and JDK proxy won't hold here.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond - I have only found wider scoped beans injected into session-scoped beans. The other way around as you described it. So I guess `scoped-proxy="interfaces"` won't be necessary?

Comment: @theFriedC Yes, in this case you can safely remove it